# Specify row number start point

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have some sample data below and I want to use row_number but make it start when the value is 0 for col3
I have tried the below but it doesn't work

```
row_number() over (partition by col1,col2, case when col3 = 0 then 1 end order by col4 desc) as row2
```

| Col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | row_number (output wanted) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | def | 7 | 500 |  |
| abc | def | 0 | 300 | 1 |
| abc | def | 1 | 200 |  |
| abc | def | 0 | 2 | 2 |
| abc | def | 4 | 30 |  |

Answer (score 1):

Have  NULL for others

```
case when col3 = 0  
   then row_number() over (partition by col1,col2, col3 order by col4 desc) end as row2
```

Answer (score 0):

A row number is just a running count of rows. So you should be able to do this:

```
select
  col1, col2, col3, col4,
  count(case when col3 = 0 then 1 end)
    over (partition by col1, col2 order by col4 desc, ctid) as row2
from ...
order by col1, col2, col4 desc, ctid;
```

I have added Postgre's internal `CTID` in order to get a deterministic order for the case of duplicate col4 values. If such duplicates are not possible, you can remove `CTID` from the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: yeah I need something that works if col4 has the same value.

Comment: I've just found out about Postgre's `CTID` and updated my answer.

Comment: One problem is I'm using redshift and it doesn't have CTID

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys but I just figured it out.

I did

```
case when col3 =0 then row_number() over (partition by col1,col2,col3=0 order by col4 desc) else null end as Row
```

so what this did was a running count for both sets of 0 and non0 and I'm just hiding the non 0 ones with the case.

Comment: This is similar to what Serg suggested in their answer. However, you'll want a deterministic order so that the row number matches the order in which you show the results. This means here, too, you should add the `CTID `to the `ORDER BY` clauses as I've shown in my answer.

Comment: Hi, I'm using Redshift so it doesn't have CTID

Comment: Then why is your request tagged `postgresql`? If there is nothing built-in to help you get a deterministic order, then add a technical ID to the table for that purpose.